# Android Mail app keeps resizing the content

Tags: android, html, css, email, window-resize

Even that I set fixed width and min width to tables

```
<table width="534" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width: 534px;">
<tr>
<td width="534" border="0" align="center" style="min-width: 534px;">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And also Use this:

```
<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-moz-text-size-adjust:none;">
```

But the Android Mail app keeps resizing the content, its funny because image width are resepected (I get the scroll), but all `<p>` get same size than viewport,

EDIT:

Some screens, to actually show the issue,

Original:
[image]
Android Mail:
[image]

Any idea what am I missing, here?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c614r0eL/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think preventing the reflow of text is actually a bad idea, since the mail will be seen in a variety of screen sizes and it is desirable that it readjusts, so it's responsive.

Anyway, try adding a `display:block` and `width` to P style.

Comment: I know.. but the client want it "as is"

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `table-layout:fixed` for the table i think it will work